# Display count of files/items that match specific conditions before listing those items

Tags: php, if-statement, count, conditional-statements

I can't seem to find the answer anywhere. I'm trying to count the number of files in an FTP folder that meet certain conditions. I am using the following:

```
/*
 * Filename examples: 
 * Store Evaluation_10950_2019-12-03_6980.pdf
 * Store Survey_13532_2019-11-29.pdf
 */

$file_list = ftp_nlist($ftp_connection, "."); 
$currentDate = date('Y-m');

$countFiles = count($file_list);

// Title of Completed Evaluatons
echo '<strong>'.$countFiles.' Completed Evaluations:</strong><br><br>'; 

foreach($file_list as $file) {
//Only get Current Month PDF files
    if ((strpos($file, '.pdf') !== false) && (strpos($file, 'Store Evaluation') !== false) && (strpos($file, $currentDate) !== false)) {
        // Remove Store Evaluation_ from string
        $strippedEvals1 = ltrim($eval, 'Store Evaluation_');
        // Remove store number from string
        $strippedEvals2 = strstr($strippedEvals1, '_');
        // Remove _ from string
        $strippedEvals3 = str_replace('_','',$strippedEvals2);
        // Remove everything after the date in string
        $strippedEvalDate = substr_replace($strippedEvals3 ,"", -8); 
        // Get just the store number
        $strippedEvalStoreNum = substr($strippedEvals1, 0, strpos($strippedEvals1, "_")); 
        // Print store number and date
        echo "<strong>".$strippedEvalStoreNum."</strong> (".$strippedEvalDate.")<br>";
    }
}
```

I am able to list all of the files according to the conditions I specified; however, now I want to count them and say how many there are at the top. The code above obviously outputs the number of all files in the folder without the conditions.

I have tried `$countFiles = count(strpos($file_list, '.pdf'));` just to test a single condition, but that produces nothing. What is the correct way to go about this?

Comment: other then the answer is given below, you could simply regex what you want from the string rather than stripping it down piece by piece

Comment: I've been trying to figure out regex / preg_match to make it work for what I want, but had such a hard time I figured I would come back to it. For now, stripping it down seemed to at least get me the results I want so I can move on and come back to it when I'm not frustrated with it. Lol. The file names consist of: (1) "Store Evaluation_" or "Store Survey_", (2) a 4 or 5 digit store number, (3) Year-Month-Day, (4) a 4-digit submission code. Example:  "Store Evaluation_10950_2019-12-03_6980.pdf". I need to output: "10950 (2019-12-03)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of echo'ing the conditions as you loop you could store it in an array and then output it at the end with a `count()` on the `$output` array:

```
$output = array(); //create an empty array to store our output

foreach($file_list as $file) {
//Only get Current Month PDF files
    if ((strpos($file, '.pdf') !== false) && (strpos($file, 'Store Evaluation') !== false) && (strpos($file, $currentDate) !== false)) {
        // Remove Store Evaluation_ from string
        $strippedEvals1 = ltrim($eval, 'Store Evaluation_');
        // Remove store number from string
        $strippedEvals2 = strstr($strippedEvals1, '_');
        // Remove _ from string
        $strippedEvals3 = str_replace('_','',$strippedEvals2);
        // Remove everything after the date in string
        $strippedEvalDate = substr_replace($strippedEvals3 ,"", -8); 
        // Get just the store number
        $strippedEvalStoreNum = substr($strippedEvals1, 0, strpos($strippedEvals1, "_")); 
        // Print store number and date
        $output[] =  "<strong>".$strippedEvalStoreNum."</strong> (".$strippedEvalDate.")"; //add to array instead of echo
    }
}

echo '<strong>'.count($file_list).' Completed Evaluations</strong><br><br>'; 

echo '<strong>'.count($output).' Evaluations Met My Conditions:</strong><br><br>'; //echo the number of files that met the conditions

echo implode('<br/>', $output); //echo the converted file names
```